# Loading PDFs in WKWebview with UIPageViewController unloads the PDF when swiped right or left for an already loaded PDF

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am moving from `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`. My problem is when I put these in `UIPageViewController` and I have multiple PDFs. then swiping left or right of `UIPageViewController` unloads the previously loaded PDF.

This happens because `webview.LoadRequest` happens in `ViewDidLoad()` method.

I have tried reloading the same in `ViewWillAppear()` but it doesn't solve my problems as it still happens.

Code:

```
   WebKit.WKWebViewConfiguration webViewConfig = new WebKit.WKWebViewConfiguration();
   webViewConfig.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
   webViewConfig.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
   webViewConfig.AllowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true;

   var jscript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";
   var userScript = new WebKit.WKUserScript(new NSString(jscript), WebKit.WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, true);
   WebKit.WKUserContentController wkUController = new WebKit.WKUserContentController();
   wkUController.AddUserScript(userScript);
   webViewConfig.UserContentController = wkUController;

   webView = new WebKit.WKWebView(new CGRect(0, 1, screenWidth, screenHeight - 115), webViewConfig);

   NSUrl url = new NSUrl(MyUrl);
   NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(url);
   webView.LoadRequest(request);
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your UIPageViewController? There's a hack that you can do to make this work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56216968/uipageviewcontroller-with-wkwebview?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Saamer. But I didn't get the hack in provided link. Would be a great help if you can help me out in this. 
In my UIPageViewController. I am just getting the Next and provious View controllers for the same in which PDFs are loaded in Webview.    @Saamer

Comment: If you can update your original post adding the code of your UIPageViewController anyone could try to replicate your issue by running the code locally and then look for a solution.